# How to tilt camera by default instead of overhead view?

Tags: android, google-maps

I have mapView in my fragment and I'm displaying lots of pins on the map.

By default camera is on top of map and displays from overhead side.

By dragging a point on map - by two fingers - and moving fingers down then camera tilts.

I want to display my map by default from this tilted view.

Is it possible to do that? Thanks.

=====

## Update

I have following lines of code but seems doesn't work :(

```
@Override
    public void onMapLoaded()
    {
        if (this.mMap != null)
        {
            CameraPosition position = new CameraPosition.Builder().tilt(30).build();
            this.mMap.animateCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.newCameraPosition(position));
        }
        // Subclass should override this to implement the feature
    }
```

==========

## Answer

For those who has same problem this is my solution which is working fine.

```
protected synchronized void animateMapTo(final LatLng pin, final Float zoomLevel, final boolean useAnimation)
    {
        final GoogleMap map = this.getMap();
        if (!this.isSafe() || pin == null || map == null)
        {
            return;
        }

        // Set zoomlevel to current level if not set.
        final float cameraZoomLevel = zoomLevel == null ? map.getCameraPosition().zoom : zoomLevel;

        // Build camera position
        CameraPosition position = new CameraPosition.Builder()
                .target(pin)
                .zoom(cameraZoomLevel)
                .bearing(0)
                .tilt(45)
                .build();

        // Stop any animations
        map.stopAnimation();
        if (useAnimation)
        {
            map.animateCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.newCameraPosition(position));
//            map.animateCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.newLatLngZoom(pin, cameraZoomLevel));
        }
        else
        {
            map.moveCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.newCameraPosition(position));
//            map.moveCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.newLatLngZoom(pin, cameraZoomLevel));
        }
    }
```

Comment: What does "seems doesn't work" mean? What exactly happens?

Comment: have you try to change tilt value and also use .zoom()  to build camera

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[Build a new CameraPosition](https://developers.google.com/android/reference/com/google/android/gms/maps/model/CameraPosition.Builder), [create a CameraUpdate from it](https://developers.google.com/android/reference/com/google/android/gms/maps/CameraUpdateFactory.html#newCameraPosition%28com.google.android.gms.maps.model.CameraPosition%29), then [move](https://developers.google.com/android/reference/com/google/android/gms/maps/GoogleMap.html#moveCamera%28com.google.android.gms.maps.CameraUpdate%29) or [animate](https://developers.google.com/android/reference/com/google/android/gms/maps/GoogleMap.html#animateCamera%28com.google.android.gms.maps.CameraUpdate%29) the map camera to that position.

Comment: Thanks, I added my sample code to question for other's reference.

Comment: all the links are broken. gg

Comment: Stupid google changed their root URL. Thanks for letting me know. Fixed.